# Trying to add a character limit to a text input but javascript and php show different string lengths

Tags: php, javascript

I notice the problem when I use the character `¦`. For the 3000 character limit, I can fill the textarea with 3000 ampersands. The javascript showing the string length says 3000 and when I post the text, php says it's 3000. If I try 3000 of `¦` then javascript again shows 3000, but php shows a lot more, in the 5000's. `¦` has a html code `&#166;` and `&brvbar;` so I don't know why php is showing a problem. Why is this?

Edit: PHP shows that each `¦` has a string length of 2, while other characters have the usual 1. I notice that any character with an ASCII code higher than 160 has a php string length of 2: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: please some code how you are counting length in php..

Comment: When the textarea is posted I'm just echoing `strlen($_POST['text'])`

Comment: strlen('|'); prints 1 in php.

Comment: please post echo $_POST['text'];

Comment: `echo strlen("¦");` echoes `2`

Comment: `echo $_POST['text'];` when text contains 1 `¦` is just `¦`

Comment: when we echo echo strlen('¦'); interpreted by php as strlen('Â¦'); and echo it 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be dealing with multicharacter UTF-8 chars. To have those counted correctly, assuming your files are actually UTF-8, try this:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8"); // Not actually needed in this case, but add it if you use preg_ functions
echo mb_strlen("¦");
```

[mb_* functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) are meant to deal with multibyte characters.